# How's currentNode injected into a CQ5 JSP file?

Tags: aem, sling

I am reading the [guides](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/getting_started/overview.html), and in the first example, `home.jsp` is defined as:

```
<%@page session="false"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sling" uri="http://sling.apache.org/taglibs/sling/1.0"%>
<sling:defineObjects/>

<%@ page import="javax.jcr.Repository,
                   javax.jcr.Session,
                   javax.jcr.SimpleCredentials,
                   javax.jcr.Node,
                   java.net.URLEncoder,
                   java.util.List,
                   java.util.Iterator,
                   javax.jcr.Value,
                   javax.jcr.RepositoryException"%>

<html>
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
  <title><%= currentNode.getProperty("title").getString() %></title> 
</head> 
<body> 
  <div>
    <h1><%= currentNode.getProperty("title").getString() %></h1>
    <br>
    <%= currentNode.getProperty("body").getString() %>
  </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

I thought `<sling:defineObjects>` injects the `currentNode`, but according to the [tag docs](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/sling-scripting-jsp-taglib.html), it is not.

So what is injecting it then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial thought was correct, `<sling:defineObjects>` does in fact set that value. The tag docs you link to describe the attributes of the tag itself (i.e. the values you can pass INTO the tag), not the values that it sets.

If you look at the code for the DefineObjectsTag [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.sling/org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.taglib/2.1.0/org/apache/sling/scripting/jsp/taglib/DefineObjectsTag.java), you can see that `currentNode` is one of the things that gets added to the page context.